# How to batch delete specific folder in user's share

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to devise a way to batch delete a specific folder within many user backup folders. What I have is a server that stores user backups by username, within a parent directory called Users.

The issue is when the backup script was created it was configured for XP paths, which still works for Windows 7, but I need to update it so that the paths are specific for Win 7.

The folder I'd like to delete is Documents and Settings. I know enough to use robocopy (in case of long file names) to do each user folder individually but it's very time consuming, and I have many servers to do this on (multiple locations, each with dedicated file servers).

I'm looking for assistance/ideas on how to approach this, not necessarily for someone to write the script for me. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have a flat list of directories per user you could simply iterate over all directories and delete the documents and settings from there:

```
for /d %u in (*) do rd "%u\Documents And Settings" /S /Q
```

Before running this you have to CD into the directory containing the users directories or specify the base directory before the star:

```
for /d %u in (\\myserver\backupstuff\usersdirectories\*) do rd "%u\Documents And Settings" /S /Q
```

Please take care: running this command will automatically delete all directories including subdirectories (assuming the user this is run under has enough permissions)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll ponder this and test some things, and report back.

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  I had to nest another for loop because each user folder has a sub folder named according to assigned computer name.

For /d %%u in (C:\USERS2\*) do (
Echo %%u
For /d %%v in (%%u\CDATABUP\*) do (rd "%%v\C\Documents And Settings" /S /Q)
)

Answer (score 0):

For /d %%u in (C:\USERS2*) do (
For /d %%v in (%%u\CDATABUP*) do (rd "%%v\C\Documents and Settings" /S /Q)
)